# Browse RabbitMQ queue on-demand and process the data after

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Trying to read a queue. It has 4 messages in the queue and each message is very small - Like "hello world" small!  Strangely, sometimes it is slow, sometimes it is fast and I am not sure why. I am guessing it is not a great way to browse a queue, but for my purposes, I cannot consume the queue in a normal way - I need to get the contents of the queue on an on-demand basis and then process it after.  Can anyone help me?

```
public async Task<new List<string>()>> GetMessages()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost"};
    using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    var queueDeclareResponse = channel.QueueDeclare("myQueue", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

    var receivedMessages = new List<string>();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());

        receivedMessages.Add(message);

        if (receivedMessages.Count == queueDeclareResponse.MessageCount)
        {
            tcs.SetResult(receivedMessages);
        }
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

    // Wait for the consumer to finish processing messages
    var result = await tcs.Task;

    return result; // RETURN TO CALLER TO DO STUFF WITH LIST OF MSGS...
}
```

Comment: You should not open re-create the connection every time, if possible, it's quite expensive. Maybe you could keep the connectino open, cache the messages, and return the cache contents on demand. Also, if you're saying it's slow sometimes, you should profile which part of the method is taking long.

Comment: (Btw, you might also want to have a look at `BasicGet` for this use case.)

Comment: @marsze Do I just use BasicGet rather than BasicConsume? Could you provide an example any chance please? I tried but I only got the first messages N number of times (N = number of messages in the queue) and was not able to get messages behind

Comment: If you use BasicConsume - prefetch count of unacked messages applies to your channel (if not specified by consumer, default from server will be used), ie, you will not be able to consume more than that until you ACK them. This is feature which allows some sort of coordiantion between parallel consumers. With BasicGet you can fetch entire queue. So yeah, try BasicGet in batches + some timeout at last batch (if nothing got in say 1 second - complete TCS and return result).

Comment: @eocron any chance you could give an code example of this please? I also have a bounty and it is going to waste!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost"};
            using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            var all = await GetAllMessagesAsync(connection, "myQueue", CancellationToken.None);
        }

        private static async Task<List<string>> GetAllMessagesAsync(IConnection connection, string queueName, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            using var model = connection.CreateModel();
            model.QueueDeclare(queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
            model.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
            var result = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tmp = await GetNextMessageAsync(model, queueName, ct, 
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                    if (tmp == null)
                        break;

                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp.Body.Span);
                    result.Add(body);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static async Task<BasicGetResult> GetNextMessageAsync(IModel model, string queueName, CancellationToken ct, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan checkInterval)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            
            using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
            cts.CancelAfter(timeout);
            while (true)
            {
                var tmp = model.BasicGet(queueName, false);
                if (tmp != null)
                    return tmp;

                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(checkInterval, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return model.BasicGet(queueName, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Queues are generally designed not to be a "database" to view messages, RabbitMQ - is one of those cases, it is not designed to pull messages, and basic.get is not efficient (it doesn't let you get messages in batches), but for UI/small queues it should be fine.

**PS**

From my experience in various queues, **RabbitMQ is worst of them**:

- It is overcomplicated in terms of frameworks and server configuration, eat a lot of resources, hard to manage.
- Can [split-brain occasionally](https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html) (which in practice lead to all/some messages lost) with hard to do manual recovery.
- Memory overflow is also common on both sides, constant monitoring required
- Clients are statefull and sometimes they can just hang pretty much everywhere. Non recoverably without service restart. Need constant monitoring through healthchecks.
- You can forget about gracefull shutdown, client hangs in background. Event worse - in finalizer sections.
- Queues with a lot of consumers/producers leads to connection drainage.

**Use Kafka if you can**:

- It is simple (it really is just a bunch of log files and consumers with offsets)
- Gives same performance (over 10-100k rps is easy-peasy on three nodes)
- Can do everything RabbitMQ can and what broker should do.
- Lets you view queues in any manner (through watermarks) and many Cloud providers has it by default as one of their assets.
- Has 3rd party UIs to view/manage topics/partitions/messages

Comparison is pretty obvious here: https://www.projectpro.io/article/kafka-vs-rabbitmq/451